# Managing SQL Server Connections

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, connection-pooling, sqlconnection

What is the the best practice for SQL connections?

Currently I am using the following:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(CONNECTIONSTRING))
{
    sqlConn.Open();
    // DB CODE GOES HERE
}
```

I have read that this is a very effective way of doing SQL connections. By default the SQL pooling is active, so how I understand it is that when the `using` code ends the `SqlConnection` object is closed and disposed but the actual connection to the DB is put in the SQL connection pool.  Am i wrong about this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's most of it. Some additional points to consider:

- Where do you get your connection string?  You don't want that hard-coded all over the place and you may need to secure it.
- You often have other objects to create as well before your really use the connection (`SqlCommand`, `SqlParameter`, `DataSet`, `SqlDataAdapter`), and *you want to wait as long as possible to open the connection*.  The full pattern needs to account for that.
- You want to make sure your database access is forced into it's own data layer class or assembly.  So a common thing to do is express this as a private function call:

.

```
private static string connectionString = "load from encrypted config file";
private SqlConnection getConnection()
{
    return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
}
```

And then write your sample like this:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = getConnection())
{
    // create command and add parameters

    // open the connection
    sqlConn.Open();

   // run the command
}
```

That sample can only exist in your data access class.  An alternative is to mark it `internal` and spread the data layer over an entire assembly.  The main thing is that a clean separation of your database code is strictly enforced.

A real implementation might look like this:

```
public IEnumerable<IDataRecord> GetSomeData(string filter)
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM [SomeTable] WHERE [SomeColumn] LIKE @Filter + '%'";

    using (SqlConnection cn = getConnection())
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Filter", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = filter;
        cn.Open();

        using (IDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                yield return (IDataRecord)rdr;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that I was also able to "stack" the creation of the `cn` and `cmd` objects, and thus reduce nesting and only create one scope block.

Finally, a word of caution about using the `yield return` code in this specific sample.  If you call the method and don't complete your `DataBinding` or other use right away it could hold the connection open for a long time.  An example of this is using it to set a data source in the `Load` event of an ASP.NET page.  Since the actual data binding event won't occur until later you could hold the connection open much longer than needed.

Comment: point 1: I store my connection strings in the <connectionstring> section of the app/web.config
Point 2: Is this something i should worry about.  I normally do SqlConnection, then open it, then create my sqlCommand and then take if from there.
Point 3: We do all our DB access from a class lib.  I dont like doing DB access form the core application.  Is it worth my while to create the getConnection method??

Comment: Since you use a class lib for all db access, it's a simple thing to make the connection string part of the class lib's .config file rather than the .config file that will be global to the entire app.  This should be good enough to enforce a clean data layer separation, but at the same time there's no go reason to make the method public either.  That should address points 1 & 3.  For point 2, it probably doesn't hurt anything to have it open for an extra line or two, but it's not helping either.  I'm editing in another reason you might want to do it that way.

Comment: Your `yield return` example is slightly misleading. A function built around `yield return` does not start executig till the first call of `MoveNext()` on the `IEnumerator`. So even if you call the function, the connection will not be opened till you start iterating over the results.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That's a feature, not a bug (see the 2nd bullet point).

Comment: Sorry I was unclear, I meant to say the description of your `yield return` example is slightly misleading. It talks about holding the connection open once you call the method, but it does not. I do agree that it holds the connection open once the enumeration starts and you should try to complete your binding as quickly as possible to close it. I think the phrase *"If you call the method ..."* is was what made me pause  and write up the comment, I just don't know what could go in its place that is better descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's [Patterns and Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/default.aspx) libraries are an excellent approach to handling database connectivity. The libraries encapsulate most of the mechanisms involved with opening a connection, which in turn will make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of using is correct, and that method of usage is the recommended way of doing so.  You can also call close in your code as well.

Comment: Thanks.  The way that i understand it that when the "using" is finished and that calles SqlConnection.Dispose(); that ultimatly calls SqlConnection.Close()

Comment: @Neale - Yea, SqlConnection.Dispose() will call Close if it is required.  If the connection was already closed it simply releases the handle back to the ado.net provider which is then free to put it in a pool or actually close it.

Answer (score 0):

Also : Open late, close early.

Don't open the connection until there are no more steps left before calling the database. And close the connection as soon as you're done.