# C# SQL when/how do I close the connection?

Tags: c#, sql, connection

I was using this code:

```
public class SQLConnection : IConnection
{
    private SqlConnection _sqlConnection = null;

    //bunch of interface implementations for my project

    //the destructor
    ~SQLConnection()
    {
        if(_sqlConnection != null)
        {
            if(_sqlConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                _sqlConnection.Close();
            }
            _sqlConnection.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

This was working well until some time ago, when I started receiving this error: **Internal .Net Framework Data Provider error 1**

After googling a bit, I found [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.close.aspx) (the Caution part) and I think that's what's happening to me.
My class was managing the connection state opening and closing each time, but now that it seems I can't manage it this way, is there any other way that I can do this without having to go to every function that I use the connection and call `connection.Close()` explicitly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Managing SQL Server Connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911786/managing-sql-server-connections)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always use 'using' for safely disposing the connections.

```
using(var _sqlConnection = new SqlConnection())
{
     //code here
     _sqlConnection.Open();
}


//Safely disposed.
```

Also, it is never a good idea to use destructor explicitly in C# code unless you have unmanaged code.

Comment: I should've adopted this standard a long time ago, but I just never had any issues not using (pun unintended) this... it'll take a while to add this to all blocks of connection in my code but I guess I had to start some time... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably receiving this error when one code is trying to access SQLConnection that has been already  garbage collected. This usually will happen in cases like this one

```
 SqlConnection sqlConn;

 using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection())
 {
    sqlConn = sqlConnection;
    sqlConnection.Open();
 }

 sqlConn.Close();
```

I know this example looks silly as it's overly simplified, but it happens often when programmers tend to share a connection object between Managing Classes. Look for any recent changes in your code. Maybe you're passing an instance of a connection between multiple objects. One of those objects gets Garbage Collected and in turn the connection gets disposed too.